# Use Yii2-user for user registration in Yii2 Rest Api

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I want to implement  user registration/login process in my project in which i have web client application made in `angular` and mobile client is on `android`.

I am using REST for client/server communication. I have installed `yii2-user` in my `yii` developed back-end. What I want is  to create a rest api in  such a way that each of my client application use `yii2-user` for user registration and login process. So that in client if user want to register  the request will be handled by `yii-2` user module? Any suggestion that how can I achieve this?
Or is there any better way to make REST api for  registration and authentication in `Yii2`?

Comment: have u tried anything?

Comment: For registration you could have a look at the existing registration code of yii2-user plugin. For login you could build a oauth interface.

Comment: @devOp Do i need to make an UserController which extendes ActiveController  and give it a path of yii2 user model? Could you please elaborate more  on it? my basic concern is to make user signup/signin  rest Api so that mobile and web client can consume it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the yii2-user controller e.g dektrium "UserController" and extend it from \yii\rest\ActiveController then you can specify the model class in the UserController as

```
public $modelClass = 'dektrium\user\models\User';
```

In the rest post request use some parameter to give json response for rest request. i.e

```
register-form[username]=YOURUSERNAME&register-form[password]=YOURPASS&register-form[email]=EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM&someparam=true
```

In the controller

```
$model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->register()
```

will successfully register the user.

You can extend the idea from here. cheers :)

Comment: is there a way to do that without modifying dektrium user module classes?